# How to use salsa20 counter nonce?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, nonce

1. I am not sure if I got it right: a counter of messages can be used as/instead of the nonce?

I mean a message like this:

> Header(2bytes) | counter(8bytes) | Body(n bytes encrypted) | HMAC-SHA1

with counter = 1 (63 of the bits=0) is ok?

2. I understand that I should never use the same key with the same nonce twice.
   What do I do when a new connection is started and counter starts from 1 again?

Comment: WRT 2: use a new key. Consider doing a key exchange with the long term secret inserted of encryption.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I cannot change the password;I have no storage facility where to save the new key.

Comment: I didn't suggest a different password or to store a key anywhere other than ephemerally in program memory.  Perhaps you should explain your problem in more detail and/or higher a consultant.

Comment: Btw, what is HMAC-SHA128 supposed to be? You should be using the full authentication tag of SHA1 or SHA256.

Comment: @ Artjom B
Yes, it is supoosed to be the tag resulted after applying HMAC with SHA128.

Comment: Well, there is [no SHA-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm). The smallest SHA produces 160 bit output.

Comment: @ Artjom B You are right; I was under the (wrong) impression that SHA 1 produces 128 bit output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that I should never use the same key with the same nonce twice. What do I do when a new connection is started and counter starts from 1 again?

If you re-use a nonce with the same key, [this happens](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/108/13022). You should store the counter, which you use as a nonce, somewhere on the client, increment it for every message that you send and write it back to storage before you send that message. This is important, because if you fail to write it back, but send the message, the next message will use the same counter. You really should not send the message if you can't write the counter back.

If you cannot store something like a counter on the client, then you can randomly generate the nonce. 64 bit does not provide much space for good collision resistance. You should expect to get the first nonce collision after 2<sup>32</sup> messages with the same key. If you have much much fewer messages than this, then you can simply generate a random nonce and be fairly sure that there won't be a collision. If you want to be extra sure, use XSalsa20, which uses a 192 bit IV/nonce.

> I am not sure if I got it right: a counter of messages can be used as/instead of the nonce?

*Nonce* means *number used once*. If you always increment the counter, then you will always have a different number which you use *once*. So, yes, a counter can be used as a nonce.

Comment: Regarding your comment on using counter as a nonce, if the counter is stored in a unsigned 64 bit, even though it is incremented each time, it will eventually wrap around to 0 .. will that be still considered as nonce ?

Comment: @Jake No, that would not be a nonce anymore. You would need to use a fresh key at some point before it wraps around. If you don't want to contact everybody who needs to receive those messages, you could just add a key counter and each time that you would wrap around with the nonce, you would hash the key to get a "new" key and set the nonce to 0. You can then denote this advancement of the key with a second counter value stored alongside the ciphertext and the nonce.

Comment: I think I get it ... before it is `HMAC (key, msg, nonce (counter))` .. then when counter reset, we do .. `HMAC (hash(key), msg, nonce (reset to 0))` ..  also put a key counter. So basically use concept of hash chain for new key.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would be one of the many ways of accomplishing this task.