# Using 64 bit counter as nonce for HMAC

Tags: cryptography, hmac, nonce

I have a situation where I need to add a nonce to a HMAC calculation of a message sent between two machines. I am considering using an unsigned 64 bit counter as a nonce.

```
 // key pre-shared between sender and receiver
 HMAC(key, message || nonce)
```

I will increment the counter after each message. The receiving machine will verify the HMAC and increment its counter. I searched online and I get the point that a nonce cannot be repeated, but I also read that a counter can work as a nonce.

Since the 64 bit value will eventually wrap around to zero, can such a counter be considered as a nonce ?

Comment: Make an estimate when it will reach 0. I doubt 2^64 "random order" nonces will be stored for checking (as opposed to counters where one only needs to check against the highest counter). Try it with 2^16. Otherwise there is the 128 bit UUID.

Comment: I plan to store only the latest counter. What do you think of @Arthom's suggestion in the comments for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968641/682869

Comment: Seems a way to do it, I think Arthom is better in the topic than me.

Comment: A nonce should not be repeated _with the same key_.  Calculate roughly how long it will take for the nonce counter to loop back to 0 given the expected level of use.  Change your key regularly well within that time, and reset the counter to 0.  What you _must_ ensure is that the nonce/key combination is never repeated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww okay, will keep in mind.

Comment: What do you think would happen if you did repeat this nonce? HMAC doesn’t use a nonce, just a key and data. Something like GCM mode does use a nonce, and it’s important not to reuse a nonce with a given key in GCM. It doesn’t really make sense to apply security considerations from one scheme to another, unrelated scheme. You don’t include any details of what you’re exactly doing, but my guess would be there is no problem with reusing a “nonce” here.

Comment: If it were the case that your scheme was somehow vulnerable to nonce reuse, then it would also mean that HMAC has a vulnerability when then last part of any two messages were the same, which isn’t the case as far as I’m aware. I’m no cryptographer, but it doesn’t look like you have anything to worry about here. Of course this illustrates the principle that you shouldn’t do your own cryptography.

Comment: @matt Generally nonces are required to avoid replay attacks. They may not be part of the input of the HMAC (and they cannot, as the input is just a key and message) but they certainly can be part of the message. In other words: nonce is not a requirement for secure HMAC use, but is part of the security of the message.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I put the nonce in the message for the reason you mentioned i.e. to avoid replay when attacker sees the message and HMAC.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

> Since the 64 bit value will eventually wrap around to zero, can such a counter be considered as a nonce?

`2^64 = 18446744073709551616`. This number is pretty large. If you send *one million* messages per second, you will have to send messages for *thousands* of years until your 64-bit nonce wraps.

Comment: An attacker could also be sending messages though, just to wrap the counter. Will still take too long probably, but imagine a local attacker on a 10Gb ethernet connection or even somebody local. So it depends on the details.

Comment: He mentions that "The receiving machine will verify the HMAC and [then] increment its counter", so I kinda assume that there is a secret key involved (which the attacker does not know).